# How to set IST timezone in MySQL server?

Tags: mysql

I host my site in 1and1 hosting. My server time zone is USA based. Now the problem is time. When taking reports, it shows the wrong output.

I tried this:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = "Asia/Calcutta";
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

The main thing is, I am the super user.

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+05:30';
```

Also I tried this one, but same error.

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

(it gives the output as SYSTEM)

1. How to set IST time in 1and1 hosting?
2. How to change the privileges?
3. How to avoid this type of problems in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain MySQL server several time zone go through this link
[MySQL Server Time Zone Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html)

And for setting privileges go thorugh this :-
[The MySQL Access Privilege System](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html)

Comment: Thank you for response, yes i studied the your link but i dont know how to apply. because all the queries make errors.

Answer (score 12):

To set IST, run this in MySQL Server

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+5:30';
```

To check current time in MySQL Server

```
SELECT now();
```

Answer (score 1):

To set MYSQL timezone simply login on server to mysql using mysql -uusername -p and then enter password to enter mysql server
There set timezone value as required in my case I need IST so

```
SET SESSION time_zone = '+5:30';
```

[image]

Then run  `SELECT NOW();`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, go to the file that has the code for the insert query of the time/date
then paste this php code in that file:-

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
```

And you're done! You should not face any problems now:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'Asia/Calcutta', use 'Asia/Kolkata', this at least solved my problem for SQLite3.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use the "date_default_timezone_set" function to set the date to your location.

```
<?php

    $myTimeZone = date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Douala");

    $date = date("Y : M : D H:i:s);
    //display the current date according to your location.
    echo $date;

   ?>
```

[find out more](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)